# Identificar uma palavra específica em uma String do C++, existe alguma função pronta para isso? Ou só na unha mesmo?

Tags: c, c++, c++11

Olá,

Eu estou recebendo uma série de strings(linhas) de um arquivo .txt e colocando-as em um vector. Mas tem um problema, as strings vêm com um início indesejado, 
exemplo:

```
  Depende: lsb-release
  Depende: libatk1.0-0
  Depende: libc6
  Depende: libcairo-gobject2
  Depende: libcairo2
  Depende: libdbus-1-3
  Depende: libdbus-glib-1-2
  Depende: libfontconfig1
  Depende: libfreetype6
  Depende: libgcc1
  Depende: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  Depende: libglib2.0-0
  Depende: libgtk-3-0
  Depende: libpango-1.0-0
  Depende: libpangocairo-1.0-0
  Depende: libstartup-notification0
  Depende: libstdc++6
  Depende: libx11-6
```

Eu gostaria de remover o início de cada uma delas, o "Depende: ".
Existe alguma função pronta para isso ou eu vou ter que fazer na unha mesmo? Cada linha dessa eu já coloquei dentro de um vector.

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas maneiras de se fazer isso, uma delas sendo com [`std::string::find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) e [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr): encontrando a posição do espaço após `Depende:` e criando uma substring que começa a partir dessa posição.

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::string s = " Depende: lsb-release";
    const size_t p = s.find_last_of(' ');
    std::string pacote = s.substr(p + 1);
    assert(pacote == "lsb-release");
}
```

Outra possível maneira é usar [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) diretamente, passando o número de caracteres a serem pulados, caso você souber que a string sempre começará com `" Depende: "`.

Ainda outra maneira é utilizar [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace), pra remover localmente esse prefixo da string:

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::string s = " Depende: lsb-release";
    const size_t p = s.find_last_of(' ');
    s.replace(0, p + 1, ""); //< Substitui " Depende: " com "".
    assert(s == "lsb-release");
}
```

Também existe a solução com regex (como visto na [resposta do @MarcosBanik](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289685/39641)), mas evito usá-la por conta de sua controvérsia.

Comment: VALEUUU!! MUITO BOM TAMBÉM!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[regex_replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/) pode ser o que você procura.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string line1{"Depende: lsb-release"};
  std::string line2{"Independe: lsb-release"};
  std::regex exp("^Depende: ");
  std::cout << std::regex_replace(line1, exp, "") << "\n";
  std::cout << std::regex_replace(line2, exp, "") << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As respostas foram ótimas, talvez eu refaça o meu código. Eu acabei terminando ele na unha mesmo. Mas gostei de saber que eu posso "automatizar" isso. Eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
#ifndef PACOTE_H
#define PACOTE_H
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Pacote
{
    public:
        /*Metodo que retorna o nome do pacote definido pelo usuário*/
        std::string GetnomeDoPacote(){
        return nomeDoPacote;}

        /*Metodo que define o nome do pacote a ser trabalhado*/
        void SetnomeDoPacote(std::string variavelNomeDoPacote){
        nomeDoPacote = variavelNomeDoPacote;}

        /*Metodo que retorna as dependencias do pacote*/
        std::vector<std::string> GetdependenciasDoPacote(){
        return dependenciasDoPacote;}

        /*Metodo que extrai as dependencias do pacote de um arquivo .txt linha a linha, para que elas sejam trabalhadas*/
        void SetdependenciasDoPacote(std::string TXT){
          std::string linha;
          std::ifstream dependenciasTXT (TXT);
          if (dependenciasTXT.is_open())
          {
            while ( getline(dependenciasTXT,linha) )
            {
              dependenciasDoPacote.push_back(linha);
            }
            /*O primeiro e o último elemento do arquivo .txt não nos enteressa, pois eles não contem o nome de
            nenhuma dependencia a ser baixada*/
            dependenciasDoPacote.erase(dependenciasDoPacote.begin());
            dependenciasDoPacote.pop_back();
            /*Para cada elemento adquirido através do comando 'apt-cache depends', temos as classificaçoes "Depende", "Recomendado" e "Sugere".
            Precisamos remover essas strings do vector que armazenará essas dependências, logo, o esquema abaixo busca pelo primeiro elemento dessas
            strings, afim de identifica-las e removêlas atráves do comando erase.*/
            for(int linha = 0; linha < dependenciasDoPacote.size(); linha++){
                for(int elementoDaLinha = 2; elementoDaLinha < sizeof(dependenciasDoPacote[linha]); elementoDaLinha++){
                    if(dependenciasDoPacote[linha][elementoDaLinha] == 'D'){
                        dependenciasDoPacote[linha].erase(dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin(), dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin()+10);
                    }
                    else
                    if(dependenciasDoPacote[linha][elementoDaLinha] == 'R'){
                        dependenciasDoPacote[linha].erase(dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin(), dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin()+12);
                    }
                    else
                    if(dependenciasDoPacote[linha][elementoDaLinha] == 'S'){
                        dependenciasDoPacote[linha].erase(dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin(), dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin()+9);
                    }
                }
            }
            dependenciasTXT.close();
          }

          else{
            dependenciasDoPacote.push_back("Não foi possível encontrar o arquivo de dependências! :(");
            }
        }

        /*Metodo que retorna o nome do repositório PPA do pacote, definido pelo usuario*/
        std::string GetrepositorioPPADoPacote(){
        return repositorioPPADoPacote;}

        /*Metodo que define o nome do repositório PPA a ser trabalhado*/
        void SetrepositorioPPADoPacote(std::string nomeDoRepositorioPPA){
        repositorioPPADoPacote = nomeDoRepositorioPPA; }

    private:
        std::string nomeDoPacote;
        std::vector<std::string> dependenciasDoPacote;
        std::string repositorioPPADoPacote;
};

#endif PACOTE_H
```

Eu utilizei o método erase e o begin. Tá, não foi exatamente na unha, mas foi quase na unha. 
dependenciasDoPacote[linha].erase(dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin(), dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin()+9);

com o erase eu defino que eu quero apagar, e com o begin eu digo que eu quero apagar pela frente. Estou trabalhando com um vector. a linha 0 do vector tem uma determinada quantidade de elementos, e, se eu digo 'dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin(), eu me refiro ao primeiro elemento(elemento 0). No trecho acima, eu digo que quero apagar do elemento 0 até o elemento 9.

dependenciasDoPacote[linha].erase(dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin() /*do elemento 0*/, dependenciasDoPacote[linha].begin()+9 /*ao elemento 9*/);

Isso dá certo porque o arquivo .txt que está sendo trabalhado segue um padrão. Ele sempre começa no elemento [linha][2] do vector. E sempre começa ou com Recomendado, ou com Depende, ou com Sugere. Logo, eu sei, através dos ifs e elses o que eu estou apagando ou não. Se for recomendado, que começa pelo elemento [linha][2] pela letra 'R', eu apago até tal elemento, se for Sugere, que começa pela letra 'S', eu apago até tal elemento.... Enfim. Por favor, apontem erros ou más práticas no meu código.